# How to build responsive layout in Xcode (not auto layout)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout, constraints

I am making chat app and have create persona component which is implemented in view using `Container view`. I want it to have maximum width so on iPhone it will be full-width but on iPad in centre with fixed width. Also on iPhone in landscape orientation it should be scrollable (I already use `Scroll view` but exactly in landscape orientation it behaves weirdly).

[image: Create persona component]

This is how create persona component looks like. It had all elements in `View` but Xcode told that their are errors. Now it has all elements separate, they have width <= 350 and trailing and leading margins >= 0 – and all this works well but when I insert this component in view (it looks like this):

[image: It looks like this]

...using `Container view` wrapped with `Scroll view` it behaves weirdly. I gave `Container view` constraints at top, bottom, left and right all equal to 0 but Xcode show warning that `y` is not equal to expected. It can't make `Container view` as large as `Scroll view`. Also I want to make it scrollable so when screen height is not enough to show whole form you can scroll it. But now when you rotate screen to landscape view size of `Container view` also changes so `Scroll view` is not scrollable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do this in `Storyboard` by selecting the `Attributes inspector` of the element you want to customise based on the screen size and clicking on the `+` sign on the left of the property you want to customise. However, this only provides very limited options, so you are better off doing this either in code and checking the screen size programatically or using different `Storyboards` for both iPad and iPhone.

To use different storyboards, you can do the following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation

    if screenWidth > x { //use iPad storyboard
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifier")
        self.window.rootViewController = vc
    } else {
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "OtherStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "otherIdentifier")
        self.window.rootViewController = vc
    }
...
}
```

Comment: If to create different stroryboards how to implement it to existing one and switch them depending on device?

Comment: And what about scrollable Container View? Without Scroll view it is not scrollable at all but using it nothing changes, only appears bounce effect

Comment: For fixing your scroll view you should ask a different question, since that has nothing to do with this one, you probably have flawed constraints.

Comment: Will it happen only when app launches? If yes than I need to have absolutely two separate storyboards? Is there way to use one storyboard but for some views switch it?

Comment: About answer about scroll view, I thought both questions are because of constraints cause I read that to set maximum width for view I can just set constraints with width and margins. And scroll problems are due to of constraints

Comment: You can put the code anywhere in your app, but if you use two completely separate storyboards, it makes sense to only check it at app launch. You can do this only for some ViewControllers as well, in that case you should perform the same check before navigating to the view controller that is not the same on both devices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151977/discussion-between-masiama-and-david-pasztor).